# Is it possible to LDAP query users common to a set of groups

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I need a list of all the users common to a known collection of groups, using a single LDAP query of our Active Directory.  It would seem, from the our reading so far, that such is not possible, but I thought it best to ask the hive mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible with an attribute scoped query.  It requires W2K3 AD or later but will give you the all of the users that have a particular attribue i.e. membership in a group or in your case multiple groups (intersection of groups).  One of the best examples is from Joe Kaplan and Ryan Dunns book "The .NET Developers Guide to Directory Services Programming" for AD work it's hard to beat look at page 179 for a good walk through.

**Caveat**:At this point you are past trivial searches in AD and a number of things are becoming important like the search root, scope and the effect of searching through some potentially HUGE set of data for the items you want. Looking through 50 or 60K users to find the members of a group does have an effect on performance and be prepared to do paged results or similar in case the dataset is large. Kaplan/Ryan do an excellent job of down to earth work to get you where you need to be.  That said, I have used them on two AD projects with great success.  Being able retrieve the data from AD without recursive queries is VERY worth while and I found that it is fast as long as I control the size of my dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(&(objectCategory=Person)
    (&
        (memberOf=CN=group1,dc=company,dc=local)
        (memberOf=CN=group2,dc=company,dc=local)
        (memberOf=CN=group3,dc=company,dc=local)
    )
)
```

This is similar to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823069/active-directory-a-script-to-find-all-users-that-arent-in-a-set-of-groups), except there I wanted all users who were NOT members of groups. You'll need to delete all the whitespace for most query tools to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in a single query if your groups contain nested groups.

You would need to write some code that recursively resolves the group members and does the logical equivalent of an "inner join" on the results, producing a list of users that are common to all the original groups.